# Passing object to a function in lambda std::thread (C++): attempt to use a deleted function

Tags: c++, object, lambda, stdthread

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class A {
  private:
    std::mutex my_mutex;
  public: 
    void A_function(){
        some work with the mutex;
    }
};
void B_function (A a){
     a.A_function();
}

int main () {
     A a;
     std::thread t([&a]{
          B_function(a); // error here
          });
     t.join();
}
```

However, I get this error:

> error: attempt to use a deleted function « A »
> error: attempt to use a deleted function « std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&) »

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, is that a proper [mcve] that you show? And is that the full and complete error output, copy-pasted verbatim?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/31Gd8s. The cause of the error is in the code you _didn't_ show us. My guess: `A` is not copyable.

Comment: I tried to improve the example. I am using an std::mutex in class A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::mutex` is not copyable, therefore, you naturally cannot copy an object of type `A`, which has a subobject of type `std::mutex`.

As a workaround, you can pass an argument to `B_function` by reference instead of by copy:

```
void B_function (A& a)
{
     a.A_function();
}
```

Don't know though whether it suits your needs to work with the original object instead of with its copy.